# Compare two columns of different files and replace another using AWK

Tags: awk

I have these two files:

**file1**

```
F729981596975938577090932834 18 A1472861
F446395652970789701163827646 10 B35234576
F446395652970789701163827646 10 C96515097
F02508215481124974649572984 18 D83395117
F02508215481124974649572984 18 E26810286
```

**file2**

```
F02508215481124974649572984 28
```

What I've been trying to accomplish to no avail is:

- Print all lines in **file1** and...
- If the first column of **file2** matches with the first column of **file1**, then replace the second field of **file1** with the second field of **file2**.

**desired outcome**

```
F729981596975938577090932834 18 A1472861
F446395652970789701163827646 10 B35234576
F446395652970789701163827646 10 C96515097
F02508215481124974649572984 28 D83395117   <- Second field successfully replaced.
F02508215481124974649572984 28 E26810286   <- Second field successfully replaced.
```

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
awk ' NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2 ; next } { $3 = a[$1] ; print } ' file2 file1

F729981596975938577090932834 18
F446395652970789701163827646 10
F446395652970789701163827646 10
F02508215481124974649572984 18 28
F02508215481124974649572984 18 28
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are using the third field, and you are not checking if the array contains the value.

If you set it to the second field, without checking the array, the first 3 lines will not find a value in the array and the current $2 column value will be empty.

You could check if the first field is in the array. If it is, set the second field to that value.

```
awk ' NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2 ; next } { if ($1 in a) {$2 = a[$1]}; print } ' file2 file1
```

Output

```
F729981596975938577090932834 18 A1472861
F446395652970789701163827646 10 B35234576
F446395652970789701163827646 10 C96515097
F02508215481124974649572984 28 D83395117
F02508215481124974649572984 28 E26810286
```

Or slightly shorter

```
awk ' NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2 ; next } { if($1 in a) $2 = a[$1]} 1' file2 file1
```